# Python Logging Impeding Call from PHP Script

Tags: php, python, logging, argparse

My server is a mix of Python and PHP - the PHP manages incoming messages from users, then sends it through to Python with arguments to process, then returns the appropriate calculation:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import argparse

def addTwoArgs(a, b):
    return a + b

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # create the top-level parser
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument('integera', type=int, help='first integer')
    parser.add_argument('integerb', type=int, help='second integer')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.integera and args.integerb:

        result = addTwoArgs(args.integera, args.integerb)

        print(result)
```

While I'm sure I could do better here (and advice on how to better set this up to send through to PHP would be appreciated), it works in the current form. It's just a matter of a call from PHP:

```
exec("python /home/ubuntu/php_test.py 60 7", $output);
```

This will give an answer of 67. All good.

However, I'm trying to add in logging in order to know when PHP is making its calls. Even before formally adding a handler, the script practically 'quits' when trying to create a file handler - or when calling `handler = logging.FileHandler("addTwoArgs.log")` in the example below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import argparse
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# create a file handler (PHP CALL FAILS HERE)
handler = logging.FileHandler("addTwoArgs.log")

# other logging commands
....
....
logger.addHandler(handler)

def addTwoArgs(a, b):
    return a + b

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # create the top-level parser
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument('integera', type=int, help='first integer')
    parser.add_argument('integerb', type=int, help='second integer')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.integera and args.integerb:

        result = addTwoArgs(args.integera, args.integerb)

        print(result)
```

Considering this script works perfectly when called via SSH, it took a while to pick up that logger could be a problem. I'm thinking this is a problem with user privileges. I can run the script fine through SSH which has quite comprehensive privileges, but I will be calling the PHP script from a web browser (which I think uses www user here).

I've tried changing the file permissions to 666, with no change.

I've also tried calling the script with Python 3, with no change.

```
exec("/usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/php_test.py 60 7", $output);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
handler = logging.FileHandler("addTwoArgs.log")
```

Will attempt to create a `addTwoArgs.log` file in the **current working directory**, which may not be writable by the user that's executing the process (and will therefore fail). See at the end for an example of how this fails.

To fix your issue, use a full path instead, and ensure the user has write access to that path:

```
# Edit your code:
handler = logging.FileHandler("/var/log/addTwoArgs/main.log")

# Run this once before in your shell
mkdir -p /var/log/addTwoArgs
chown www-data:www-data /var/log/addTwoArgs
```

Ensure that you replace `www-data` above with the actual user your web process is running as.

---

Here's me trying to use a log file in a directory I don't have permission to write to:

```
>>> handler = logging.FileHandler("/addTwoArgs.log")  # / is only writable by root
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 911, in __init__
    StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 936, in _open
    stream = open(self.baseFilename, self.mode)
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/addTwoArgs.log'
```